# How to add tags for products

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I've got Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 2.0 and I need to know if there is any way to add tags for products because I can't find any component for this purpose.

Comment: There are some commercial plugins that claim to do just that. Google `virtuemart tagging` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find extension in the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/), infact they have there own category — [Virtuemart Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions).

As you're using Virtuemart 2 plugins should work on your VM2/Joomla 1.5 setup.

If you need to look for older extensions you can try the [Joomla! 1.5 Extensions Archive](http://archive.extensions.joomla.org/) which also has it's own [Virtuemart section](http://archive.extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions).

Comment: I've found only plugin VM2Tags and it's commercial.